# How to virtualize my physical home file server?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, home-server, file-server

I have a home file server, currently has around 5TB of data, nothing fancy just old hardware (low budget) having a pentium dual core with 8GB ram. It runs snapraid so I can use dissimilar hard drives available at home and it also gives me a fair amount of fault tolerance. Its not used 24x7 per-say and I would say the machine is under utilized.

I want to virtualize the server to reduce power bills and to better utilize the hardware I have. I also have another machine running proxmox.

I havent used raid or LVM because of non standard disks of varying age, size, etc and in the worst case that I am not able to recover a failed disk, with snapraid, I lose only the data in the disk that failed unlike raid or LVM.

I was wondering if there was a way to convert the physical server to a virtual one and yet be able to use the dissimilar hard disks and still have at least a the minimal fault tolerance I have now. I looked at ceph (supported with proxmox now) but I think it requires at least 3 nodes. Can somebody suggest a technology that works with proxmox or perhaps even a virtualization strategy?

EDIT: Currently, I am also using aufs to pool the disks. Can this be done (or needed) when virtualized? How is backup/fault tolerance handled in the nodes when it contains VMs with a large amount of data?

Comment: Vmware vCenter Converter ?

Comment: So you are suggesting that the 5TB (growing) data be made a virtual disk (vmdk?) file? What about the fault tolerance/backup? How should I configure the physical disks?

Comment: No that would be silly, to my knowledge you can use physical disks with VMs so I guess you should be able to use your existing configuration.

Comment: So would you recommend keeping the basic stuff like snapraid and pooling on the physical server itself and moving just the OS to the VM or mounting the hard disk on the VM amd setting up snapraid and pooling on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

If it has Windows OS then either Oracle Virtual Box or VMware Workstation 10.  The use of VMware esxi 5.x boots the PC into a vmware OS.  Then you would have to virtualize all the OS(s).  Using vmware esxi you would not be able to use snapraid as all your data would have to be put in a VMware disk.

Local visualization products such as Virtual Box or VMware Workstation avoid this kind of pain.

Linux also has many VM products.  xen,kvm and more.

Comment: I am looking more into proxmox... since its debian based I think I can run snapraid on it. Though not sure if that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried passing RAW devices through ProxMox, but that would be something to look at. You could use unRAID too which has beta support for running virtualized VMs inside through Xen. However, unRAID is not free. While it is not very expensive, the registration key they provide is dependent on the USB UUID. So if you USB fails, I am not sure how easy it is for the to issue you a new registration key for the new USB drive.